# automatically fill up values for missing date rows

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table similar to the following

```
Date   | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4 | column6
1 july | 33   | 0    |  0   | 0    | xyz
1 July | 0    | 20   | 0    | 0    | xyz
1 July | 18   | 0    | 0    | 0    | abc
3 July | 0    | 0    | 0    | 11   | abc
3 july | 23   | 0    |  0   | 0    | xyz
4 July | 0    | 40   | 0    | 0    | xyz
4 July | 57   | 0    | 0    | 0    | abc
7 July | 0    | 12   | 0    | 0    | xyz
```

And I'm looking for output as below in a stored procedure in sql server 2005.

```
 Date   | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4 
 1 July | 51   | 20   | 0    | 0 
 2 July | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0
 3 July | 23   | 0    | 0    | 11
 4 July | 57   | 40   | 0    | 0
 5 July | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0
 6 July | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0
 7 July | 0    | 12   | 0    | 0
```

As you notice, I want it to put automatically 0 values for missing date. I'm wondering if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can generate by default all date in a month  from the actual **table:1** means solution 'll be very simple... like...

```
 SELECT     date  AS Date ,
            ISNULL(qty1, '') AS qty1,
            ISNULL(qty2, '') AS qty2,
            ISNULL(qty3, '') AS qty3,
            ISNULL(qty4, '') AS qty4,
    FROM    your_table_name where for_all_date
```

otherwise you want to do some what like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE put_null ()
AS 
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME
DECLARE @End_date DATETIME
    BEGIN             
      SELECT TOP 1 @start_date = date FROM your_table_name ORDER BY Date   
      SELECT TOP 1 @End_date = date FROM your_table_name ORDER BY Date  DESC 
        WHILE(@start_Date < = @End_date)
        BEGIN
        SELECT  @start_date AS Date ,
                ISNULL(qty1, 0) AS qty1,
                ISNULL(qty2, 0) AS qty2,
                ISNULL(qty3, 0) AS qty3,
                ISNULL(qty4, 0) AS qty4,
        FROM    your_table_name

        SET @start_date = DATEADD(DAY,1,@start_date)
        END
    END
```

Hope this w'll solve your problem....

Answer (score 0):

You could either use GETDATE() on the date column to automatically get it (unless you intend on there to be missing date values). In the other case, you could set up a default value (or DEFAULT CONSTRAINT) in that column, making the default value 0 if that is what you mean. Or do you mean you want to go back into already inserted rows and edit the columns?

Answer (score 0):

In Stored procedure you can handle it as **isNull(column,0)** it will work for both insert or retrieval query in Stored Procedure

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can't understand what you exactly mean here. where i shall write `isnull(column,0)`?